# Show that $X$ is regular iff for every point $x$ and its nbd $V$ there is nbd of $x$ such as $x \in U \subset cl(U) \subset V$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Show that $X$ is regular iff for every point $x$ and its nbd $V$ there is nbd of $x$ such as $x \in U \subset cl(U) \subset V$.

I'll start with implication $(\Leftarrow)$.

Let $F$ be an arbitrary closed set $F\subset X$ and $x \in F^c$. From assumption, since $F^c$ is open, there exists nbd of $x$ such as $x \in U \subset cl(U) \subset F^c$. Moreover, $(cl(U))^c$ is an open set containing closed set $F$. Of course $(cl(U))^c \cap U = \emptyset$. We have shown, that $X$ is regular.

$(\Rightarrow)$Suppose $X$ is regular. Take an arbitrary point $x\in X$ and its nbd $V$.
Set $V^c$ is closed and $x\notin V^c$. From the fact, that $X$ is regular we find open sets $U_1, U_2$ such as $x\in U_1$,$V^c \subset U_2$ and $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$. Of course $U_1 \subset V$. But how do we know, that $cl(U_1) \subset V$?

Any hints would be great.

Answer (score 3):

First $U_1 \cap U_2 = \varnothing\implies U_1 \subset U_2^c$. Since $U_2$ is open, $U_2^c$ is closed. Thus $cl(U_2^c) =U_2^c$. Plus $V^c \subset U_2\implies U_2^c\subset V$. Hence
$$
cl(U_1) \subset cl(U_2^c) =U_2^c\subset V
$$